# Noun meaning "something destructive"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am trying to think of a noun that describes things that are destructive.
More specifically, a noun describing all devices and chemicals that cause destruction, encompassing explosives and chemicals like thermite and napalm.

I was thinking of using the word "destructive" itself as in having a list, the header being "Destructives:" in the same way you'd use the word "Explosives" to describe nouns that are explosive.

Can I use the word "Destructives" and if not are there any others I could use?

By the way, I am using this word in the context of a header of a list like I said above.

Thanks!

EDIT: I think I'll just use the word "Destructives". I guess it doesn't make perfect sense, but it kind of does because since it's the header of a list, it's describing each object on the list as destructive.
Also "explosives" makes sense so why not.

Comment: If these "destructives" are tools designed by humans for the primary purpose of harming or killing living things (especially other humans), then ***weapons*** will suit. Or even *weapons of mass destruction* (WMD, in the parlance). But, for example, a supernova is incredibly destructive, but not a *weapon* (yet). Does your word have to also cover supernovae?

Comment: No, I am talking about man-made devices and chemicals that are not specifically made for harming living things, but for destroying structures and objects; things like explosives and some pyrotechnics. (for example thermite and dynamite are not generally used as weapons)

Comment: Besides 'explosives' that you already used (don't see why you can't just use that), how about 'incendiaries'?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a word that includes things that explode (explosives), things that start fires (incendiaries) and other things that cause destruction (such as acids like hydrofluoric acid). Basically, something that destroys objects, equipment, structures and the like. Thanks for the word incendiary though, that'll come in useful for what I'm writing.

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no such word, but I do agree that such a word would prove most useful :)... (that was an evil smile btw). There are the vague terms 'destroyers' and 'annihilators', but these are too vague to specifically mean what you desire.

Comment: @Ambidextroid The acid is an example of a *corrosive*. In general, these are termed [safety] *hazards*, but that is (a) more general than you probably want and (b) puts the focus on their dangerous (to humans), rather than destructive (to objects) nature.

Comment: What's wrong with simply *"Destructive items/materials"*?

Comment: @TrevorD Just that it's .... uninspiring. Bland. Not reflective of the power and danger associated with such things. In a word: mundane.

Comment: @DanBron Have you read OP's edit? He's proposing just to use "Destructives". That's no less 'bland', but is a non-word.

Comment: @TrevorD It's less bland in the general sense that concision lends force. Like concentrated meaning. But if you like "destructive substances", upvote NVZ's answer, where he suggests exactly that.

Comment: @DanBron I intentionally avoided "*substances*" alone, because OP referred to "all *devices* and chemicals", else I would have upvoted NVZ's answer.

Comment: @TrevorD There's mention of *devices and chemicals* in my answer.

Comment: @NVZ Apologies - I didn't notice that. But, notwithstanding your quoted definition, I wouldn't normally understand "substance" to include "devices" and would therefore probably not use for that reason.

Comment: @TrevorD I see your point. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Explosive (n.)** means **explosive (adj.) substance**. — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explosive)
Similarly, **destructive (n.)** to mean **destructive (adj.) substance** is understandable.

**Destructive substance** — [LectLaw](http://www.lectlaw.com/def/d044.htm)

> Any explosive substance, flammable material, infernal machine, or other chemical, mechanical, or radioactive device or matter of a combustible, contaminative, corrosive, or explosive nature. USC 18

For further reading: [18 US Code Section 31 Definitions](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/31)